# Why printed output contains '\n' instead of breaking lines?

Tags: python, bash

I'm getting json file and converting it to a yaml file with a script.

I used python code in a bash shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

#python - ${INSTALL_DIR}/storm-tmp.json > ${INSTALL_DIR}/storm.yaml << EOF
python - ${INSTALL_DIR}/storm-tmp.json << EOF
import os
import sys
import json

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
  obj = json.load(f)
lines_to_write = []
for key in obj:
  value = obj[key]
  value = value.replace('\\n','\n')
  print(('%s: %s')%(key, value))
EOF
```

I expected the output to be something like:

```
storm.log.dir: /logs
storm.zookeeper.servers: 
  - zkserver-0.zookeeper.com
  - zkserver-1.zookeeper.com
  - zkserver-2.zookeeper.com
storm.local.dir: /data
nimbus.seeds: 
  - stormnimbus-0.storm.com
```

But the printed output is:

```
storm.log.dir: /logs
storm.zookeeper.servers: \n - zkserver-0.zookeeper.com\n - zkserver-1.zookeeper.com\n - zkserver-2.zookeeper.com
storm.local.dir: /data
nimbus.seeds: \n - stormnimbus-0.storm.com
```

I have no idea why the `\n` character is not translated as a new line character.

How can I resolve this?

EDITED

input:

```
{
  "storm.log.dir" : "/logs",
  "nimbus.seeds" : "\\n - stormnimbus-0.storm.com",
  "storm.local.dir" : "/data",
  "storm.zookeeper.servers" : "\\n - zkserver-0.zookeeper.com\\n - zkserver-1.zookeeper.com\\n - zkserver-2.zookeeper.com"
}
```

Comment: What does the input (for the expected output you shared)?

Comment: `lines_to_write = []` is not used so you can remove it.

Comment: @AllanWind I added the input. Yes, it can be removed. I just tried some other ways, and forgot to remove that line.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? When I use that PYTHON script only, it prints well. But using that python codes in a bash script gives the unwanted output.

Comment: `print("a\\n - stormnimbus-0.storm.com".replace("\\n","\n"))` seems like it works fine to me`

Comment: My advise would be to either port the remaining of the bash script to python (it's a more sane programming language; and I love bash), or split the python code in a separate file.

Comment: You can also do `value = value.replace(r'\\n','\n')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this kind of nested backslashes in bash is painful.  You need:

```
  value = value.replace('\\\\n','\\n')
```

With that, your script works for me.

**By the way**
You can replace this:

```
for key in obj:
  value = obj[key]
```

with this:

```
for key,value in obj.items():
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. `\\n` is not replaced to `\n`, so `\\n` is printed as `\n`.. I see. So, even though it's python code, because it's run in a bash script, it follows some of bash rules? I don't get this because it's a PYTHON script in a bash script.

Comment: Yes.  Bash does its own translation of backslashes.  It doesn't know you're using Python code.  It's just expanding strings.  The \\\\n becomes \\n, the \\n becomes \n, and Python turns the \n into a newline.  Really, what you're doing here is not sustainable.  As a side note, you don't have to pass the file name as an argument.  You can embed it in the Python code.  Bash will substitute it. `with open("${INSTALL_DIR}/storm-tmp.json",'r') as f:`

Answer (score 0):

Here is reading from the file using 'EOF' to suppress expansion (of \):

```
#!/bin/bash

python - 1.json <<'EOF'
import os
import sys
import json

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
  obj = json.load(f)
for k, v in obj.items():
  print(('%s: %s') % (k, v.replace('\\n', '\n')))
EOF
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't read from a file, which is the requirement.